# Change color resolution in a xaml file of a windows phone app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Inside my WP7 app, a gradient on some of my images looks pretty ugly, I guess that's because of low color resolution. How can I change this in XAML? I know there is a way in XNA but I don't remember it in detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue you are talking about is related to the "bands" being visible in your gradient, you need to adjust the `BitsPerPixel` property in the your app manifest.

Details [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20111113/death-to-banding-windows-phone-devs-please-upgrade-your-apps-to-32-bitsperpixel/). The setting is also mentioned in the [official MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=VS.92%29).

Comment: Thank you, sir. It helped a lot! I was already wondering if I would need some 32-bit-image, but it works well with 16-bit-png.